# How do I make this function more efficient?

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, stl, time-complexity

I'm trying to create a tiny database that contains a list of people, their names, ID, and their income as time passed on. Using this database I'd like to find their median income.

The class structure I have in mind for the people is something like this

```
class Person {
       string name;
       string ID;
       vector<int> Incomes;
 };
```

And the class structure for the database overall is just a vector containing these incomes.

```
 class Database{
             vector<Person> somepeople;
 };
```

Let's say I create a function called median income that returns the median income of all people in this database. The obvious method would be to iterate through every person, and then subsequently iterate through every value in the vector of incomes to create a list that contains all values and then from that finding the median. However, this would be in O(n*k) time. Is there a way to achieve this in O(nlogn) or less, including ways provided by the C++ STL?

Comment: Why is that O(n^2)?

Comment: I don't see how: you have to take all incomes into account since every income can influence the median income, so you have to iterate through every income. That is O(n*k) for n people and k incomes per person (assuming that each person has the same number of incomes)

Comment: Consider doing what `std::string` does:  Rather than recomputing the size of the `string` every time the size is needed, `string` stores its size.

Comment: Sorry I did mean O(n*k). @Debaug. Typed it in a rush. Fixed it to make it clear.

Comment: Unless each `Incomes` is sorted, you'll have to iterate over all of them. If each `Incomes` is sorted, there might be a smart way to go about searching for the median of the *aggregate* `Incomes`; I suspect that this target would be somewhere between the smallest and largest medians of each *individual* `Incomes`.

Comment: @wLui155 I don't think finding the median would be practical if the vectors and the merged vector are unsorted. And even then it may not escape linear complexity.

Comment: Are you saying that each `Person` has more than one income?  Or do you want to say more than one *persons* income?  The latter involves `std::vector<Person>`.

Comment: Another idea, if `Incomes` are sorted: binary search for the aggregate median. For each guess, determine the total number of elements strictly smaller than/larger than it. If these two counts are equal, we have the median. Otherwise, if there are more elements smaller than our guess, the actual aggregate would be smaller than our current guess; analogous for the other case (note - this may be off?). If the range of values is `M` and we have `N` `Incomes` of size `k`, the time complexity would be `O(N * log(k) * log(M))`, which will probably be better than a scan of everything: `O(N * k)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very interesting task! I fully implemented from scratch code of two solutions for you. First solution is much shorter and uses only [standard C++ library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), second solution is several times longer and more difficult but `3x` faster than standard library solution.

You may skip whole description text below and just run C++ code provided at the bottom.

First solution implements class `StdMedianFinder` for finding median that is capable of doing 3 operations:

1. `Add(value, count)` - this allows to add several incomes of different users at a time, income is signified by `value` and `count` means how many occurances of this income all users have. You may add income of any user at any point in time, for example if your database is updated from time to time with new users.
2. `Del(value, count)` - this allows to delete incomes of a user, for example in case if user is deleted from database. value and count mean same as in Add() operation.
3. `Median()` - this method returns median of all current incomes, this is exactly what you wanted in your Question. Method is very fast, returns value immediately no matter how many incomes are there, because main time and computation consumer is Add() and Del().

As you can see above library allows to do all things incrementally, meaning that in different points in time you can update your database by adding or removing some users or parts of their incomes. Incrementality gives very fast speed for small updates, meaning that if you had 1000 incomes that took for example 100 micro-seconds to add them to structure, and later added/removed 10 more incomes then they will take just 1% of initial time - just 1 micro-second, because `10 incomes / 1000 incomes = 1%`.

Class above uses only [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and nothing else. As it is known std::map implements sorted (by keys) container using [Red-Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) binary search tree. Adding/removing one element to my class takes approximately time of adding/removing one element to std::map plus one advance of iterator (`++it;` or `--it;`). std::map for adding/removing one element uses approximately `O(Log(N))` time, where `N` is amount of elements already in container. Hence total time for adding/removing `N` elements in my class takes `O(N * Log(N))` time.

In your Question you noted that you want very fast solution. Both of my solutions give `O(N * Log(N))` time for adding `N` different incomes. If you have `n` users and `k` incomes for each user, as you said in Question, then my `N = n * k`, it means time is `O(n * k * Log(n * k))`. But there are good news - this is full time when doing only very first computation of Median, later calls to median give immediate result, and as it often happens in all DataBases new users are added or removed later from time to time, and if you add/remove a user that has `k` incomes then you need only small extra time `O(k * Log(n * k))` to update my class and re-compute Median. When adding single user, **Important** is not to do whole re-computation of all users (whole database), but only to Update class with incomes of this single user.

For second solution that is much bigger, and `3x` times faster, I implemented from scratch so-called [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) that is not present in standard C++ library, and using this tree I implmented `BTreeMedianFinder` class that has exactly same interface of first class `StdMedianFinder`.

**Important Note** All my code below (and especially B-Tree) is not very well tested, and can't be suited for copy-pasting into Production products. Either you have to copy-paste it into just educational projects or do some extra deep testing before usage in Production.

B-Tree is implemented in such a way that besides (Key, Value) (which are income and count of same incomes) stored in leaf nodes, it also stores inside intermediate nodes maximum value of a sub-tree and total count of incomes in a sub-tree. This allows to do very fast two operation - given a value of income it answers fast what is the position of income inside a sorted list of all incomes, and given desired position of income inside sorted list it answers fast what is the value of income at that position (this second operation is used to find Median, because median is basically a value of income at position equal to half of number of all elements).

Following code has several quite large tests that check correctness and speed of three classes `BTree`, `StdMedianFinder`, `BTreeMedianFinder`. Program shows in console timings of all tests and speed measurement.

If you have [Boost.StackTrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html) library installed in your system it can be used to show stacktrace to make exceptions messages more informative. By default in my code this feature is disabled by define `#define USE_BOOST_STACKTRACE 0`, which you can change to `1` to enable.  Also work of this feature was tested fully only on Windows, for Linux system some small fixups might be needed inside includes or defines. Program binary should be compiled with symbols information included, for this add option `/Z7` in [MSVC](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) compiler and `-g` in [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)/[CLang](https://clang.llvm.org/). Only this 3rd-party library might be used as an option, besides it only standard C++ library was used in my code.

If you do debug build, don't forget to define `_DEBUG` macro, if this macro is defined than I do very many extra assertion checks in all classes of my code to do extra testing of code correctness and prevent bugs and crashes.

Code below is fully compilable and working without any modifications. If you run it executes all tests and speed measurements and shows them in console. Also click on `Try it online!` link below to see live run of this code on GodBolt Linux servers.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/W3Kss459e)

**SOURCE CODE HERE**. Due to StackOveflow limit of 30000 characters for post size, providing [source code shared](https://pastebin.com/raw/zmxXDegC) at external PasteBin service. My post with code appeared to be 41000 characters long! Also you may click `Try it online!` link above, it has same source code duplicated at GodBolt servers.

Output:

```
'Test BTree' time 1.188 sec
'Test StdMedianFinder' time 0.532 sec
'Test BTreeMedianFinder' time 0.535 sec
'Std_Finder Add' time 1.426 sec
'BTree_Finder Add' time 0.577 sec
'Std_Tree Add' time 1.249 sec
'Std_Finder Median' time 0.001 sec
'BTree_Finder Median' time 0.321 sec
'Std_Finder Del' time 1.252 sec
'BTree_Finder Del' time 0.477 sec
'Std_Tree Del' time 1.117 sec
'Test MedianFinders Speed Total' time 6.907 sec
```

Comment: @Onlyartist9 Main speed gain of my algorithm above happens due to Incremental nature of any database. To compute median of full database from scratch takes `O(n * k * Log(n * k))` time using my algorithms, where `n` is count of users and `k` is count of incomes of one user. But this only from scratch, if you computed it once, then second time it is computed immediately. And if database is updated by one user, one user added/deleted, then you incrementally update class with my algorithm which take just small time `O(k * Log(n * k))`. So full re-compute is slower, but incremental is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Well, only when there are **two** `Incomes` vectors, you can find the median of their merger in O(logk). Because, **binary search** enables that method.

But for more than that, I don't think there is any avoiding a linear traversal.

Think that even if the vectors are sorted beforehand, even then we don't know how their values compare against each other, and middle elements can randomly be in the 2nd or 88th vector.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use std::nth_element ? This is O(n)
If the number of elements is odd => the middle element is the median
If the number of elements is even => find the iterator left middle element, then right middle element min() of 2nd half
median is *leftMiddle + (*rightMiddle - *leftMiddle) / 2;